# How / Where does Adonis cache views?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am learning adonisjs. The `.env` file has an option to set CACHE_VIEWS=true. What exactly does this do? Some frameworks store the cached views in a file, and some in memory, but how does Adonis cache views?

Answer (score 0):

This variable is readed in [your configuration file](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-app/blob/develop/config/app.js#L109). Then it's used in the wrapper around [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) (in [View/index.js](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/blob/08bdca3eac4e2c6804e74a84909a66b8f33c7949/src/View/index.js#L31)).

You can find more information about [Nunjucks Cache in the documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#loader) of loaders.